# Looking for a better javascript text-matching scoring system

Tags: javascript, string-matching, fuzzy-search

I've been using [String Score](https://github.com/joshaven/string_score) for a lot of projects. It's great for sorting lists, like names, countries, etc.

Right now, I'm working on a project where I want to match a term against a bigger set of text, not just a few words. Like, a paragraph.

Given the following two strings:

```
string1 = "I want to eat.";
string2 = "I want to eat. Let's go eat. All this talk about eating is making me hungry. Ready to eat?";
```

I'd like the term `eat` to return `string2` as higher than `string1`. However, `string1` scores higher:

```
string1.score('eat');
> 0.5261904761904762

string2.score('eat');
> 0.4477777777777778
```

Maybe I'm wrong in thinking `string2` should score higher, and I'd love to hear arguments for that logic, if that is your logic. Otherwise, any ideas on a more contextual javascript matching algorithm?

Comment: Rare to see such questions for javascript! +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `score` is not taking into account repetitions then only one occurrence of `"eat"` in `string2` adds to the score so the other occurrences of `"eat"` are treated as unmatched garbage which counts against in the total score.

Many string similarity metrics behave this way, e.g. in [Edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) the more non-matching characters the lower the score and repetitions are treated as non-matching.

It's not clear to me from reading the [source](https://github.com/joshaven/string_score/blob/master/string_score.js) what algo it is using, but the score variables

```
var total_character_score = 0,
  start_of_string_bonus,
  abbreviation_score,
  fuzzies=1,
  final_score;
```

don't seem to take into account multiple repetitions.

If you want multiple occurrences to count, then it sounds like what you want is not a string-similarity algo, but a [fuzzy match algo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching) so you can find the number of matches.

Maybe [yeti witch](http://code.google.com/p/yeti-witch/) will work for you.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. My question is about finding a better option.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking into yeti witch now. You've definitely helped me understand what I'm looking for, and the vocabulary with which to search. So thank you for that :)